# AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer video frame size

Tags: ios, swift, video, avfoundation, frame

How can I get image size inside `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer`:

```
self.cameraPreviewLayer.frame = self.cameraView.frame; // (0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 568.0)
```

Image inside `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer` smaller than frame.

Comment: It's hard to tell what's going on without seeing the context. What happens if you try changing to `bounds`: `self.cameraPreviewLayer.frame = self.cameraView.bounds`?

Answer (score 10):

You can't get the actual rendered size inside the `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer` frame. You'll have to calculate it.

**Here's how you get the actual video dimensions:**

```
AVCaptureDeviceInput *videoDeviceInput = // initialised already in your app

// Here you can get the video dimensions:
CMVideoDimensions dimensions = CMVideoFormatDescriptionGetDimensions(videoDeviceInput.device.activeFormat.formatDescription);
```

From here you can calc the aspect fitting rectangle inside the `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer` frame.

Answer (score 2):

Swift Code

```
var captureSession : AVCaptureSession?

var captureInput : AVCaptureDeviceInput?{
    get{
        return self.captureSession?.inputs.first as? AVCaptureDeviceInput
    }
}

func doSomething(){
    guard let captureInput = captureInput else{ return }

    let dims : CMVideoDimensions = CMVideoFormatDescriptionGetDimensions(captureInput.device.activeFormat.formatDescription)
        //do whatever
}
```